# ¿como usar FMOD en c++ con visual studio?

Tags: visual, studio

Tengo la duda de como usar la libreria FMOD para c++ en visual studio.

```
--#include "inc/fmod.h"
int main() 
{
    FSOUND_Init(44100, 32, 0);
    return 0;
}--
```

Answer (score 2):

Debes ir a la página de FMOD (https://fmod.com/), e iniciar sesión para descargar la versión para motores gráficos personalizados.
[image: paginas de FMOD]

Una vez instalada, vas a la carpeta donde guardaste el archivo para buscar la carpeta lib, que está dentro de la carpeta FMOD Studio API/Windows/api/core. Después elijes la carpeta que corresponde a la plataforma con la que estas trabajando y copias los archivos .dll a tu proyecto.
[image: carpeta API/Windows/api/core]

También debes copiar las librerías (archivos .lib) a ls carpeta de librerías (.lib).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego buscas la carpeta lib, que está dentro de la carpeta FMOD Studio API
Windows/api/studio. Elijes la carpeta que corresponde al sistema con el que trabajas y copias las librerías (archivos .lib) a tu carpeta de librerías (.lib).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego vas a la carpeta inc que está dentro de la carpeta FMOD Studio
API/Windows/apistudio y copias los archivos en ella. Vuelves a la carpeta de tu proyecto y declaras la carpeta FMOD,donde meterás los archivos copiados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Igualmente vas la carpeta inc que está dentro de la carpeta FMOD Studio
API Windows\api\studio para copiar sus archivos. Volviendo a tu proyecto, Dentro de la carpeta de tu nuestro proyecto creas la carpeta FMOD,
donde pegas los archivos copiados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para usar la libreria en visual studio code, debes ir a las propiedades de nuestro proyecto y agregamos las librerías en la
sección de dependencias adicionales dentro de la parte de Input que está
dentro del enlazador.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con lo anterior ya podremos usar la librería FMOD en tu proyecto. Y en el archivo principal agregas las librerías fmod_studio.hpp
y fmod.hpp.

```
#include <FMOD/fmod_studio.hpp>
#include <FMOD/fmod.hpp>
```

Sobre el codigo primero debes hacer una instancia del motor FMOD.

```
FMOD::System* system;
FMOD_RESULT result=FMOD::System_Create(&system);
```

Si el sonido es 3d Establezco la velocidad del sonido, unidad de distancia y factor de escalado del
sonido ambiental.

```
system->set3DSettings(1.0,1.0f,1.0f);
```

Inicializo y preparo FMOD para la reproducción de audio.

```
result=system->init(512,FMOD_INIT_NORMAL,nullptr);
```

Cargue el sonido en memoria para la transmisión o configuración de
sonidos basados en devolución de llamadas

```
FMOD::Sound* sound;
result=system->createSound("name.mp3",FMOD_DEFAULT,nullptr,&sound);
```

Creo un canal para reproducir el sonido.Creo un canal para reproducir el sonido.

```
FMOD::Channel*channel;
result=system->playSound(sound,nullptr,false,&channel);
```

Eso seria todo, no olvides liberar el motor de sonido, canales y borrar las canciones que cargaste.

```
system->release();
channel->stop();
```

Comment: No pude evitar ver los archivos de OpenGL. Hoy en día, [glad](https://glad.dav1d.de/) es un cargador bastante bueno. Aunque glew sigue activo y sigue siendo mejor que glut.